# Sequre text inside UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The password textfield doesn't hide the password charecters to be dots.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyEqM.png]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class signupViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signup: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!

    var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        signup.enabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func didtapcancel(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func didtapsignup(sender: AnyObject) {
        signup.enabled=true
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

        if error != nil {
            if error!.code == 17999 {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error 17999", message: "ohh", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error ", message: "tt", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)}
        }

        else
        {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

                if (error == nil) {

                    self.databaseref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(self.email.text!)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ahmed", sender: nil)
                }
            })
}


        }
    )}
}
```

Comment: And your question is....

Comment: why it is not not creating user in firebase database and why the passcode doesn't appear as dots

Comment: try `password.isSecureTextEntry = true` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The error is 'tt' so what does *print(error?.localizedDescription)* reveal from that same section of code?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks

> Sequre text inside UITextField

Select Secure Text Entry for the control on the storyboard.

It's about 1/2 way down in the attributes inspector for that control.

'showing dots' and Firebase are unrelated as that functionality is part of the text field, not Firebase.

There's an additional unrelated question, which should be posted separately, and to address that more information would be needed from the statement

```
print(error?.localizedDescription)
```